# Structural dependency in F# ---- possible without mutable and nullable fields?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I would like to have two types that have each other as fields:

```
type Player<'Team>(team:'Team) =
    member this.Team = team

type DoublesTeam(playerA:Player<DoublesTeam>, playerB:Player<DoublesTeam>) =
    member this.PlayerA = playerA
    member this.PlayerB = playerB
```

(This is parametrised to break the circular dependency between types).

Question: how to create instances of these types so that they point to one another?

In C# this would be clear: create two Players without assigning the Team field (i.e. leave it null), create a Team passing two Players in the constructor and manually set their Team fields to the Team instance. To do so in F# the Team field would need to be mutable and nullable or an option type. This is highly undesirable.

Is there a way to do this without making one of the fields nullable or an option type?

Comment: If you want to think about how to actually port your code rather than a 1:1 rewrite, I suggest F# for fun and profit. In particular the following posts might be of interest http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part3/ http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/removing-cyclic-dependencies/  http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/porting-to-csharp-intro/

Comment: @Daniel Fabian Thanks for the suggestion! I read this cyclic dependence mini series a couple of times. He mentions the let rec... and... structure that kvb described but only says it doesn't work in that situation (with classes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to do it in exactly that form with classes.  However, if you switch to records, it's easy:

```
type Player<'Team> = { team:'Team }

type DoublesTeam = { playerA:Player<DoublesTeam>; playerB:Player<DoublesTeam> }

let rec t1 = {playerA = p1; playerB = p2 }
and p1 = { team = t1 }
and p2 = { team = t1 }
```

Note that you *can* do it with classes, but you have to introduce a delay of some form; the easiest way is probably to add a touch of laziness:

```
type Player<'Team>(team:Lazy<'Team>) =
    member this.Team = team.Value

type DoublesTeam(playerA:Lazy<Player<DoublesTeam>>, playerB:Lazy<Player<DoublesTeam>>) =
    member this.PlayerA = playerA.Value
    member this.PlayerB = playerB.Value

let rec t1 = DoublesTeam(lazy p1, lazy p2)
and p1 = Player(lazy t1)
and p2 = Player(lazy t1)
```

Comment: Thanks lot for the amazingly quick answer! I'm new to F# (as if it wasn't obvious...) and while creating self contained algorithms in F# has been a joy thus far, I'm hitting some problems of the above kind when trying to port a whole C# application. I'll mull some more over the design trade-offs involved.

I'll leave the question open for another day or two if you don't mind.

Comment: If you're interested in the topic from a more _conceptual_ point of view, including the introduction of a delay using `lazy`, see also this fascinating F#-related paper: [An Alternative Approach to Initializing Mutually Referential Objects](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/70151/tr-2005-31.pdf).